# Navigating between directories in python

Tags: python, string, replace, directory, escaping

I run the following sequence of commands. The aim was moving between various directories and folders based on the original directory (so it does not need to be apriori coded):

```
path=os.getcwd()
os.chdir('..')
path2=os.getcwd()
path3=path2+('\\mydir')
os.chdir('path3')
```

As a result I get an error:

> The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\work_folder\\mydir'

The directory C:\work_folder\mydir exists in the system, so the problem is in my opinion in missinetrpretation of '\'.

Thus I tried to do the following:

```
path3=path3.replace(r'\\',r'\')
```

Again I am getting error:

> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

I will apreciate any help in overcoming this problem. Thank you

Comment: how about using `path3 = os.path.join(path2, 'mydir')`?  From what I know,  you don't have to care about the separator at all anymore then.

Comment: Do you really have single quotes around `path3` in the `os.chdir` call? Please make sure that the code you show is the same as what you are actually running.

Comment: @Lester, why don't just `os.chdir(r"..\mydir")`?

Answer (score 0):

In python, instead of using `\`s in your directories, you can use `/`s instead and it'll still work.

Comment: Good morning, thank you. I have tried, but it did not work. I am not sure maybe it is the problem that I am uning Python in Windows - but  os.chdir('c:/work_folder/mydir') gives an error.

Comment: What's the error you're getting @Lester

Comment: I get:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'c:\\work_folder/mydir'
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'c:/work_folder/mydir'
But @clasherkasten had found a solution that works in my case.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a single un-escaped backslash (`\`) in a raw string. Change the line to:

```py
path3 = path3.replace(r'\\', '\\')
```

This will solve your second error (`SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`).

Comment: did not work: 
path3 = path3.replace(r"\\","\\")
os.chdir(path3)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\work_folder\\mydir'